# Printing elements of an array with a comma

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array `arr = ["test", "test 1", "test 2"]`. How would I print `test, test 1, test 2.`? Note the `"."` and the `","` in the expected output.

I know how to iterate over this by doing:

```
arr.each do |a|
    puts a
end
```

but I'm not sure how to get the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
puts arr.join(' , ')+'.'
```

with trailing period.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array#join](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-join).

```
puts arr.join(", ") << "."
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.join`

```
puts arr.join(', ')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way also using [**`Array#*`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-2A) which says :-

> Repetition — With a String argument, equivalent to ary.join(str).

```
arr = ["test", "test 1", "test 2"] 
arr*" ," << "." 
# => "test ,test 1 ,test 2."
```